# Wordpress - the_excerpt() returns the part of post content instead

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the `excerpt` of the post by using `the_excerpt()` or `get_the_excerpt()` but instead of returning the excerpt it returns a part of **post content** *including post images*. I have created theme from scratch, after all I looked into the table `wp_posts` the `excerpt` field is empty for published posts.

Is there anything I am missing or another way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What about a little more about your usage of the_excerpt() or get_the_excerpt(). Source files?

Comment: @JanNahody I am using WP_posts() to retrieve the recent posts and show it on post page as sidebar. So I have to show post thumbnail, excerpt and read more link

Answer (score 1):

In [wp-includes/default-filters.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L139), WordPress adds a few filters to handle excerpts. One of them calls [`wp_trim_excerpt`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2884), which will generate an excerpt if one doesn't exist.

Try removing that filter in your theme.  Something like

```
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );
```

should do the trick, though I haven't tested it.  You may need to do it in the  `init` action - see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168433/264) for an example (it removes a different filter, but should help).